# Wrong Module-Swift.h header is generated with import to itself

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoapods

So I am mixing swift and objc everywhere.
I have development pod called Renetik. 
It has some extensions written in swift but it's mostly objective c code. 
Now, I wrote some class and used it in main project fine and wanted to move it to Renetik development pod. When I do it somehow in Renetik-Swift.h wrong import is generated and project won't compile.

```
#import <Renetik/Renetik.h>
```

Then I experimented a lot. And found out that wrong import is generated when I actually return from swift class function type defined in pod itself. It is happening just when I try to make it in Development Pod where is mostly objective-c. Other swift extension and classes works juts when I try to modify some class to return objc class defined in pod itself.

I will write example when everything is OK. This compiles fine and I can call function testMe from main project:

```
@objc public class ReplaceMe: NSObject {
    @objc public func testMe() {
        let variable = CSResponse<NSObject>()
        variable.cancel()
    }
}
```

Just this small change and wrong header is generated as I stated before:

```
@objc public class ReplaceMe: NSObject {
    @objc public func testMe() -> CSResponse<NSObject> {
        let variable = CSResponse<NSObject>()
        variable.cancel()
        return variable
    }
}
```

I use `use_frameworks!` in podfile as `use_modular_headers!` don't work for other reasons. I m able to setup branch in Github project where this happens as this is open source.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems only not hack possibility is to create other pod just for Swift files. Define in podspec dependency to released verison, and in host application podfile add dependencies with `:path =>` .